# Unable to extract modulus, exponent from pubkey.pem

Tags: encryption, openssl

I am trying to extract modulus and exponent components from public key which is in .pem file, using below command:

```
openssl rsa -inform der -pubin -text < pubkey.pem
```

But it is showing me below error message:

```
unable to load Public Key
4339:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-47.1/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1315:
4339:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-47.1/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:379:Type=X509_PUBKEY
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the public key try to replace the der option with PEM like this:

```
openssl rsa -inform PEM -pubin -text < pubkey.pem
```

Otherwise you can extract the public key from the key.pem file like this:

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout -out pubkey.pem
```

and then run the first command again.

Comment: thanks currently it is returning modulus as - 00:a6:f0:8e:d5:68:79:d5:75:46:.. is there any way to get it as base64 encoded?

Comment: You need to add -modulus option to your command. It will appear something like this: Modulus=C8FF7903BCF39C1D6F0BDE82BA98A13DD....